# How can I create a user in embedded Firebird 3.0

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0, firebird-embedded

I need to create users in Firebird 3.0 embedded databases, but using with standard command returns error.

command:
*CREATE USER miusuario
PASSWORD 'miclave';*

return:

> ```
> Engine Error (code = 335544382): Missing user management plugin.
> SQL Error (code = -901): Unsuccessful execution caused by system error that does not preclude
> successful execution of subsequent statements
> ```

I need to create the users on both in runtime and in development.

Any idea how to solve this problem? I've looked in the Firebird documentation and can't get anything to help me.

I do not use the Firebird in server mode, only embedded.

Answer (score 0):

Firebird Embedded does not perform authentication<sup>1</sup>, and it will accept any username you specify at connect. Creating users is unnecessary, and in your case impossible because it looks like the user management plugin is not configured or available (setting `UserManager` in `firebird.conf`). However, even if that plugin was configured, it would be pointless to create users if you only use Firebird Embedded, because Firebird Embedded won't actually use the data of that user.

In Firebird, privileges are granted to usernames not to user records in a security database<sup>2</sup>. So, even though there exists no user with that username, you can grant it rights (in fact, that is also possible in Firebird server).

You can login (password is ignored) with any username when using Firebird Embedded. The logged in user will then assume any rights granted to that username.

---

<sup>1: This has always been the case on Windows, on Linux this is only the case since Firebird 3, in earlier versions on Linux, Firebird Embedded did perform actual authentication using the security database</sup>

<sup>2: Except for a small set of privileges like admin in security database and database creation privileges</sup>